# How can I setup my VS 2013 TypeScript project to compile my typescript files but exclude my node_modules?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, tsconfig, typescript1.7

I'm working on an angular2@beta project in VS 2013 after familiarizing myself with it in IntelliJ.  IntelliJ can be set to find the tsconfig.json file and, as of TypeScript 1.6, it can therefore read the "exclude" property and not attempt to compile any of the node_modules.  Now that I've moved to VS 2013 with TypeScript 1.7, I'm running into the issue where it's trying to compile the node_modules.  I've included the tsconfig.json, but from what I've read, tsconfig.json is fully supported only in VS 2015.  Is that the latest on this issue?  Is there some way to tell VS 2013 to exclude those files or to use my tsconfig.json instead?

I should also note that angular2@beta includes its typings with the rest of its source when I do an npm install.  This puts all the typings mixed in with all the files, and I assume perhaps I could have to delete all the non-.d.ts files to get the typings without all the other errors.  Previously you could use "tsd install angular2" to get the typings but this is no longer available.  A solution to this would negate the previous problem.

---

**Update**

I can get all this working on [VS 2015 - Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367106/use-angular2-with-visual-studio/34371549#34371549), but I would really like to see if I can get it working on VS 2013.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue and  wondering, since typescript is developed by microsoft and visual studio itself is not fully supporting it.

Comment: Any update on this? I need it to!

Answer (score 0):

Higher versions of Typescript will not be supported in Visual Studio 2013. But you don't need to edit and compile typescript files in one and the same IDE. It's handy but I use often different IDE's for the same project as long as the build processes are aligned (read: can be done by CLI). So yo can use Visual Studio Code for your Typescript work and compile it. Full support and Intellisense for the tsconfig file.

https://code.visualstudio.com/