# Use angular2 with visual studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

Has anyone gotten Angular2 (beta) to work in Visual Studio?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with update 1 and I  have n HTMLTypeScript project.

If I set the 'module system' to "System" I get build errors (such as: Cannot find module 'angular/core') but it will compile the ts files on save (not on build).  If I already have the application running I can refresh the page and it works.

If I set the 'module system' to "CommonJS" it will build properly but I get runtime errors such as "'require' is undefined" and "Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference".

I think I should use system because that is what works when using tsconfig.json and the lite-server (with npm start) that is used in the tutorials.

Comment: I'm running into issues with it on my question for VS 2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366928/how-can-i-setup-my-vs-2013-typescript-project-to-compile-my-typescript-files-but 
I remember running into this issue myself when I was working with it in Intellij.  The solution resolved itself when I used TS 1.6 and Exclude in my tsconfig.json.

Comment: I am using 1.7.3 and the problem is not with node-modules, it's with the TS that I wrote (from the angualr2 tutorial).  I don't think I need to exclude this, it needs to compile.

Comment: yeah, i tried too to get work the angular 2 with visual studio, but after strange behavior and multiple "boolean sh*t" errors and 8 hours of trying to solve i just shift-deleted my project...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have angular2 working with Visual Studio 2015.  I had to install [.NET 5 RC1](http://www.asp.net/vnext) to support tsconfig.json.  They have a completely new project structure which I like very much.  Here is my setup:

[image: Solution Explorer]

You'll notice that I put my app folder and ts files inside my wwwroot - that's just my preference, and it's following the angular2 quickstart.  I copied the bundled files from my node modules into my scripts folder inside my wwwroot.

I created a package.json based on the angular2 beta quickstart:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  }
}
```

Then I right-clicked on the package.json and selected "Restore Packages" and it ran the NPM install to create the node_modules folder with all the packages you see.  Then I setup my tsconfig.json like so and put it in the root:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This is key to making it work.  I actually had to reload the solution for it to see the tsconfig.json and start using it.  In addition to this, I went into my Tools > Options and set the typescript options like so:
[image: TypeScript Options]

Next I added my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sample Angular 2 App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

    <script src="scripts/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });

        System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The order of your script includes is important!  Here's my MyApp.ts file:

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
        <div>Hello from Angular 2</div>
    `
})
export class MyApp {
    public constructor() {
    }
}
```

and my boot.ts file:

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { MyApp } from "./MyApp";

bootstrap(MyApp);
```

At this point I felt I was ready to run it, so I launched it and navigated to my /index.html - but all I saw was "Hello World!".  It seemed to be ignoring my path to serve index.html and was statically writing out text.  Looking at the Startup.cs, I found the problem.:

```
namespace Angular2Demo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            // Add this!
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Remove this!
            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

By commenting out the `app.Run` and adding the `app.UseStaticFiles();` (which required installing an additional package), I was ready to try again:

[image: Eureka!]

Success!

Comment: I had tried the approach but gave up because of where node_modules was going (above wwwroot).  I will revisit it.  Thanks.

Comment: Referencing the node js files from my html page meant that at deployment I would either have to maintain the node_modules directory structure at deployment or deploy the whole whopping 40+MB node_modules as well. I didn't like this approach so I copied the angular references that I needed to my scripts folder so that only the ones I need get deployed.

Comment: Could you post a link to .net RC1 that you referenced?

Comment: Updated.  I made the text a link.

Comment: I had to click the arrow next to "IIS Express" --> CLR Type (.NET Framework) --> and select ".NET Framework" before I could get the above example to work.  +1 for @Zack solution!!

Comment: I also added:  app.UseDefaultFiles();  before  app.UseStaticFiles();  so I did not have to add /index.html to the end per - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html

Comment: Good. I added that myself later.

Comment: what do you use for managing dependencies? did you try jspm? I'm trying with jspm and modules cant be found

Comment: I have grown fond of npm.  VS2015 has some cool intellisense when I'm editing my package.json.  It will look up/autocomplete packages and versions and auto-download them when you save the file.  The node_modules folder won't show up in your project so you'll have to click the "Show all files" button.

Comment: if somebody get shocked - it doesn't work in IE for some reason...
(Chrome and Mozilla - works!)

Comment: I have complication with implementing your implementation, i just posted [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36791432/5376197). The problem is with the typescript compilation.

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş Make sure you are using backticks for your templates and not apostrophes - `

Comment: it wasn't the problem, but i get it to work, it was the `browser.d.ts` file causing the issue.

Comment: ..but still have to clean project, rebuild it, and then build it to see my changes... in short: clean - build multiple time until it works...

Comment: Could you please post source code on github? There are so many issues that can be spoiled...
For example I get this error: `Build:Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'`

Comment: Angular 2 has entered release and a lot most likely changed since this was posted, but I'll be happy to see what I can do.  In the meantime, look at this:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7786