# ASP.NET Visual Studio 2015 - TypeScript not compiling after changes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I've created a new template ASP.NET Core site, and I've just stared fiddling around with it. However, I'm finding none of the type script is compiling into javascript. Ever!

I've tried:

- Clean & rebuild
- Closing and restarting visual studio
- Stopping the site in the IIS takbar before restarting
- Closing the IIS in the taskbar before restarting
- Switching to IE or Chrome
- Running VS as admin

I created a completely new project, changed the host port so it was a different URL, before compiling I changed the "Hello world!" and *it still displays* "Hello world!". It has never even been compiled once with that!

I can put a breakpoint in Startup.cs, but any breakpoints in TypeScript "will not be hit" due to no symbols loaded.
__
I found [this](http://www.ryadel.com/en/fixing-typescript-compile-on-save-feature-in-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-5-rc1/), and have the same issue here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791432/typescript-files-not-compiling-on-angular-2-with-visual-studio-2015). None of the solutions seem to fix the problem.

I've added `"watch": true` to the tsconfig.json, and it builds fine (and I checked the SDK folders, versions 1.8 and 2.0 - so a late enough version), so typescript has no problem with the setting.

But it's still not compiling, ever!

**Edit 2** Found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7362) discussion, which says to add `"compileOnSave": true` to the tsconfiguration file. Still no result.

I can't believe how difficult it's been to get a template project to compile! It doesn't feel like it's pickup up the config file at all, as I'd had compileOnSave in the CompileOptions when it shouldn't be - yet no errors were reported. I've tried moving it alongside the wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last!

Found the issue. I had updated Node.js with a manual install and directed visual studio to it *but* I hadn't updated NPM! I'd assumed the latest version of node shipped with the latest version of NPM.

Ran `npm install npm@latest -g` to update NPM, deleted the node-modules and re downloaded packages.

All works.